# mod_pagespeed 502 bad getaway AWS WordPress refarch

Tags: wordpress, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, mod-pagespeed

mod_pagespeed gives 502 errors work with [WordPress AWS refarch](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-refarch-wordpress).

Here is my config file from /etc/httpd/conf.d/wordpress.conf file:

```
  ModPagespeedDomain https://www.xxxxxxxx.com
  ModPagespeedDomain WordP-Publi-1AC6NOPIDQV7P-893345601.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
  ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain d3ips2dzhfxmti.cloudfront.net WordP-Publi-1AC6NOPIDQV7P-893345601.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
  ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain localhost WordP-Publi-1AC6NOPIDQV7P-893345601.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
  ModPagespeedShardDomain https://www.xxxxxxxx.com \
                        https://d3ips2dzhfxmti.cloudfront.net
```

The source code displays what should be the correct path :

```
<img src="https://d3ips2dzhfxmti.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/xheader.jpg.pagespeed.ic.SMKCR2r_EB.webp" width="2000" height="1200" alt="This is a new WordPress site on Amazon Web Services" data-pagespeed-url-hash="2603895281" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);">
```

But I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error and nothing is displayed.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm getting something similar with PageSpeed and Cloudfront. When I clear the PageSpeed cache the issue is fixed temporarily, but returns a few hours later.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody somehow but I had to move to an alt solution due to lack of time.
CloudFront wasn't able to serve the requested object because it couldn't connect to the origin server.
The conf file was wrong : The 2 lines with `ModPagespeedDomain` were redundant with `ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain`another thing from what I remember had to do with `ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain` more can be found here [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html)